# Perl, How to break a loop with a signal handler sub

Tags: perl, while-loop, signals

Let's say I have an opened filehandle, or anything I have to fix before to exit the script. 
I also have a long loop and I want to break the loop if the processus receives a sigint. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Here is an illustration of the problem ;

```
use sigtrap 'handler' => \&sigint_handler, 'INT';

sub sigint_handler {
  print("\nI see you are trying to escape this evil infinite loop,
but there is nothing that I can do to help you :(\n");
}

my $the_developper_is_unable_to_end_this_mess = 1;

open(my $handle, "< some.important.file");

while($the_developper_is_unable_to_end_this_mess) {
  print("And the evil loop rolls again and again...\n");
  sleep(3);
}

close($handle);

print("everything went better than expected\n")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleanup code that should absolutely be run can be put into an `END` block:

```
END {
  print "This is run before the program exits\n";
}
print "This is some normal code\n";
```

Output:

```
This is some normal code
This is run before the program exits
```

However, `END` blocks are not run when the process terminates from a signal, unless when you implement your own signal handler – and if all that it does is calling `exit`.

So this code won't print `END` when you terminate it with a SIGINT:

```
END { print "END\n" }
sleep 4;
```

But this one will:

```
END { print "END\n" }
local $SIG{INT} = sub { exit 1 };
sleep 4;
```

These handlers are dynamically scoped, so you can put one into the loop that isn't in effect on the outside:

```
 my $run = 1;
 while ($run) {
   local $SIG{INT} = sub { $run = 0 };
   print "zzz\n";
   sleep 3;
 }
 print "done!\n";
```

Of course you can also use `sigtrap`:

```
 my $run = 1;
 while ($run) {
   use sigtrap handler => sub { $run = 0 }, 'INT';
   print "zzz\n";
   sleep 3;
 }
 print "done!\n";
```

PS: Filehandles are automatically closed when they fall out of scope / on process exit. If the handle is just reading from a file, there can't be any buffering issues or other processes depending on the handle, so that you can safely forget about `close $fh` in this case.

Comment: @derpness Thanks for the suggested edit. Setting the handlers every loop is indeed unneeded, but I wanted to place it inside the block for scoping purposes. A better solution would have been to `{ my $run = 1; use sigtrap ...; while ($run) { ... } }`. Anyway, this is really tangential to the main purpose of the code, so your suggestion was not incorporated.

Comment: The statement of sigtrap and scope, is incorrect [ from a code perspective, and possibly(?) from a human understanding ].  Adding:

BEGIN { $sigtrap::Verbose = 1; }  print "Running\n";

to prior to the "my $...", shows that the signal handler is installed at compilation time - due to the 'use' statement.  In both examples, it results in signal-handling at the global scope.